# Strange cross in a box is appearing in place of checkbox of React-native-paper

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I am using a checkbox from react-native-paper library but when I render that checkbox in my component a strange special box with a cross appears on screen as you can see in the picture. [image]

Here's my code:

**Import**

```
import { TextInput, Checkbox } from 'react-native-paper';
```

**Component**

```
 <Checkbox
                status={checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                onPress={() => { setChecked(!checked); }}
            />
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned at https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#option-with-gradle-recommended

Adding `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"` at the bottom of the file `android/app/build.gradle` I resolved my the same issue and icons are now showing correctly.