# How to fix this emoji appearing in place of a checkbox while using checkbox from react native paper?

Tags: react-native, checkbox, react-native-paper

I'm using the Checkbox component from react-native-paper and this emoji is appearing instead of a checkbox

[Baby emoji instead of checkbox screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnEge.png)

**Import**

```
import { Checkbox } from "react-native-paper";
```

**Code**

```
<Checkbox  
    status={isVisible?'checked':'unchecked'}
    onPress={()=>{
        setVisible(!isVisible);
    }}
/>
```

Comment: Please add a [mre].

Comment: Checkout this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/60797307/1283345

Answer (score 0):

Does this code snippet help inserted below? It is copied from [here](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/components/Checkbox/), and uses `checked` instead of `isVisible`.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Checkbox } from 'react-native-paper';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <Checkbox
      status={checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
      onPress={() => {
        setChecked(!checked);
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```